# Installing pygrahviz in google colab

Tags: pygraphviz, google-colaboratory

In order to install graphviz, one can follow, this example: 
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_Qb92Hj5_f2rpta67JC0JKXwE2581Ar-#scrollTo=BOa9gIcDo6GS

When I try to install pygraphviz (https://pygraphviz.github.io/) via (https://pypi.org/project/pygraphviz/)

with

```
!pip install pygraphviz
import pygraphviz as pgv
```

i get the error

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pygraphviz
```

although I installed graphviz before.
Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pip install anything.

Just import graphviz, not pygraphviz.

My minimal example:

https://colab.to/1PVtFECaDgMfVjed4XNtvyeL4pyMvPdAT

Comment: In graphviz, how do I read in a dot string like     digraph{

# Graph style
"ordering"="out"
"rankdir"="TD"

#########
# Nodes #
#########

"Add(Symbol(x), Symbol(y))_()" ["color"="black", "label"="Add", "shape"="ellipse"];
"Symbol(x)_(0,)" ["color"="black", "label"="x", "shape"="ellipse"];
"Symbol(y)_(1,)" ["color"="black", "label"="y", "shape"="ellipse"];

#########
# Edges #
#########

"Add(Symbol(x), Symbol(y))_()" -> "Symbol(x)_(0,)";
"Add(Symbol(x), Symbol(y))_()" -> "Symbol(y)_(1,)";
}

Comment: See "custom dot statement", and "using raw dot" in the doc. https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html

Answer (score 26):

Though the answer by @korakot solved the issue, but it does not address the issue of installing pygraphviz library in Google Colab.

If you have to do install pygraphviz in Google Colab then the following worked for me.

```
# graphviz is installed already, but need lib too
!apt install libgraphviz-dev
!pip install pygraphviz
```

I found this solution here: https://gist.github.com/korakot/a80c04a1945b06e2f4a053f92fecfbf9